# Uninstall Windows Virtual PC

Tags: virtualization, macos, powerpc

I was looking for Parallels in DreamSpark earlier on today and thought I would install 'Windows Virtual PC' since I found it. The only issue is I have installed it on Yosemite (2015 MBP) and Finder says 'You cannot use this application since PowerPC apps are no longer supported'.

I tried to use the uninstaller, the only issue is it has the same error (the uninstaller is a PowerPC app too)! How would I get rid of this application (I don't think I can just drag the application into the trash since the computer needed to reboot)?

Comment: I'm wondering how you installed Windows Virtual PC (which is a Windows app) or Microsoft Virtual PC which is a PPC only app on your Yosemite Mac. Please add this to your question.

Comment: There was a Mac version. It downloaded as an iso file. The application somehow supported my mac. The tools (applications 'DOS Virtual Machine Additions' and the 'Getting Started Guide') are supported, yet the Main application and the uninstaller are not. Strange.

Comment: Have a look at uninstalling it with [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) as it might show all/some of the files installed/created outside the application's bundle.

Comment: @user3439894 would it remove any kernel and other files like that if it created them?

Comment: @iProgram, I can't say as I've not tried in a situation like this, however you can see what it wants to remove before you do and maybe you can determine that it's removing everything or not.  Maybe you'll have to manually remove the .kext file(s) and associated .plist file(s) if AppCleaner can't.  Bottom line is it's worth looking at since the App's uninstaller won't run.

Comment: @user3439894 It doesn't seep to pick up all files.

Comment: It was worth a shot.  The other thing I'd do is use [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to examine the structure of the installer to see where things might have been installed that didn't show up in AppCleaner.

Comment: @user3439894 Add 'Pacifist' solution as an answer and I will accept it. I also had to use AppCleaner as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26214/discussion-between-iprogram-and-user3439894).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to determine what an installer package is going to install (or installed) and where, is to look at the installer package with [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) as it will give you the hierarchal folder layout of files installed outside the application bundle as well.

This can be used to aide in a manual uninstall as necessary if [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) does not do a complete job of uninstalling.